# Detecting whether WPF FrameworkElement is scrolled in

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, frameworkelement

I have just discovered the `FrameworkElement.BringIntoView` method, which is very useful.

However, I would also like the ability to detect whether an element actually is in view or not. In other words, a function to tell me whether BringIntoView, if I called it, would have to do any scrolling or is the element in question already within the viewable area.

Thanks.

Comment: check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx

I think the `IsFocused` property might be helpful.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work I'm afraid - IsFocused property is a more specific property related to whether that element could receive keyboard input etc. Not just whether the element has been scrolled into view.

Thanks for the answer, though!